# Как элементу массива сообщить его индекс JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Есть пустой массив `tasks[]`

в него пушатся 
`<Task  key= />`  (React)
Мне нужно в key записать индекс данного элемента в массиве.

Comment: Вероятно, сразу после помещения элемента в массив его индекс равен текущей верхней границе индекса массива, не?

Comment: ты пушишь в массив не объектное представление, а объекты реакта сразу?

Comment: @Herrgott   да,  объясни, почему это неправильно?

Comment: потому что ты пушишь объекты, у которых уже есть состояние. Тебе нужно просто объектное представление запушить и метод `render()` уже будет сам чекать этот массив и перериросовывать. Если ты конечно сделал не тупо массив, а связал его с `state` или редьюсером

Answer (score 1):

Если вы выводите эти елементы map-ом, тогда

```
tasks.map((item, i) => (
   <div key={i}></div>
))
```